# iOS and Android app old version - prevent using

Tags: android, ios

We are going to do a major update to an mobile app (both iOS and Android). When we do this update, we need to prevent the existing user using the older version anymore (in case if the new version is not auto updated) as some features might not work with the server update.

Is there any options in iOS and Andorid developer centers (for that app info) to mark that older version as cannot be used any more or to atleaset notify the users that they have to install the latest version when they try to use that app(incase they have switched off auto updates)

I have seen there are options to do it from the code by comparing it with the existing version and to notify the user. But since we have not implemented any such mechanism in our apps which is currently in the App stores, I don't think we can do the code based option for this version. That's why we are looking for other options like doing it though App store confugration etc..

Comment: Nothing exists in android for this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no solid solution for this issue.

One workaround if your app make any API calls, you can modify the response to let user know whey need to update the app. Or else, perhaps you can send a push notification to let existing user know they need to update the app.

Futhermore, you might need to implement force update mechanism, which is basically check user's current version with your latest app version, so you will know which version they are currently using. There are a few ways to do this:

1. Server side: You need to send app version to server and if it is not latest version, stop user and force user to go to AppStore/Playstore to update.
2. If you are using Firebase, you can take a look at [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config). I have not used it but I believe it would work.